# Could not proxy request. But the data is saving in the database, multer and react

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, multer

This driving me nuts. I'm debugging this for a week now and still cant fix this proxy error. But there's a catch. The data I sent in the api endpoint is still saving in the database.

Here's what I got.

I have a react component that handle inputs for announcements. This component also handles file upload.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addAnnouncement } from '../../actions/announcementActions';
import moment from 'moment';
function AddEventForm(props){
    const classes = styles();

    /* States*/

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        title: '',
        venue: '',
        description: '',
        bgColor:'#000000',

    });

    const [poster, getPoster] = useState({
        poster: null,
        fileName: ''
    });

     const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
     const [selectedTime, setSelectedTime] = useState(new Date());

     const [errors, getErrors] = useState({});
    
    /* Event Handlers*/
    const handleDate = date => {
        setSelectedDate(date);
    }

    const handleTime = time => {
        setSelectedTime(time);
    }


    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // const fullDate = `${selectedDate.getFullYear()}-${selectedDate.getMonth() + 1}-${selectedDate.getDate()}`;
        const dateDate = moment(selectedDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        const dateTime = moment(selectedTime).format('HH:mm:ss');       

        const date = `${dateDate} ${dateTime}`;

        const newAnnouncement = { 
            ...values,
            ...poster,
            date,
            dateDate,
            dateTime,
            setBy: 'SOA Admin'
        }

        let fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('poster', poster.poster);
        fd.append('title', values.title);
        fd.append('venue', values.venue);
        fd.append('description', values.description);
        fd.append('fileName', poster.fileName);
        fd.append('bgColor', values.bgColor);
        fd.append('date', date);
        fd.append('dateDate', dateDate);
        fd.append('dateTime', dateTime);
        fd.append('setBy', 'SOA Admin');

        // console.log(newAnnouncement);
        // console.log(_formData);
        props.addAnnouncement(fd);

    }

    // Component Effect for a successful Adding of Announcement
    useEffect(_ => {
       if(props.announcement.added)
          props.history.push('/ad/announceevent');

    },[props.announcement.added]);

    // Component Effect for the errors
    useEffect(_ => {
      if(props.errors)
          getErrors(props.errors)
    },[props.errors])

    console.log(props);
 
    return (
        <div>
            <DashboardAdmin>

            <Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb"  style={{ paddingBottom: '20px'}}>
                <Link color="inherit" href="/ad/announceevent" className={classes.link}>
                  <ViewListIcon className={classes.icon} />
                  Menu
                </Link>

                <Link
                  color="textPrimary"
                  href="/ad/announceevent/addevent"
                  aria-current="page"
                  className={classes.link}
                >
                <ListAltIcon className={classes.icon} />
                  Add
                </Link>
            </Breadcrumbs>

                <Paper className={classes.root}>
                      
                            <Container maxWidth="lg">

                              <Typography variant="h4" align="center">
                                    Announce Event Form
                                </Typography>
                                  <br></br>

                                <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit} enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                <Typography variant="h6">
                                 Input the details needed.
                                </Typography>

                                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                                        <TextField 
                                        value={values.title}
                                        onChange={e => setValues({...values, title: e.target.value})}
                                            id="title"
                                            name="title"
                                            label="Announcement/Event Title"
                                            fullWidth
                                            autoComplete
                                        />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <span style={{ color: "red" }}>
                                           {errors.title}
                                     </span>
                                    <br />
                                     <Grid item xs={12}>
                                        <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.formControl}>
                                            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                                                    <KeyboardDatePicker
                                                      value={selectedDate}
                                                      onChange={handleDate}
                                                      disableToolbar
                                                      variant="inline"
                                                      format="yyyy-MM-dd"
                                                      margin="normal"
                                                      id="date-picker-inline"
                                                      label="Date of the event"
                                                      KeyboardButtonProps={{
                                                        'aria-label': 'change date',
                                                      }}
                                                    />
                                            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                                      </FormControl>
                                    </Grid>
                                     <span style={{ color: "red" }}>
                                           {errors.date}
                                     </span>
                                    
                                    <br />

                                     <Grid item xs={12}>
                                        <FormControl fullWidth className={classes.formControl}>
                                            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                                                <KeyboardTimePicker
                                                 format= "hh:mm a"
                                                  value={selectedTime}
                                                  onChange={handleTime}
                                                  margin="normal"
                                                  id="time-picker"
                                                  label="Time picker"
                                                  KeyboardButtonProps={{
                                                    'aria-label': 'change time',
                                                  }}
                                                  keyboardIcon={<AccessTimeIcon />}
                                                />
                                            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                                        </FormControl>
                                     </Grid>
                                     <br/>

                                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                                        <TextField 
                                            value={values.venue}
                                            onChange={e => setValues({...values, venue: e.target.value})}
                                            id="venue"
                                            name="venue"
                                            label="Where the event will happen"
                                            fullWidth
                                            autoComplete
                                        />
                                    </Grid>
                                     <span style={{ color: "red" }}>
                                           {errors.venue}
                                     </span>
                                    <br />

                            <Grid container spacing={1} alignItems="flex-end">

                                <Grid item xs={1}>

                                  {/* 
                                     onChange={e => setObj({...obj, file: e.target.files[0], fileName: e.target.files[0].name})} 

                                    value={obj.fileName}

                                  */}
                                    <input
                                    onChange={e => getPoster({...poster, poster: e.target.files[0], fileName: e.target.files[0].name.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-')})} 
                                    className={classes.input} id="poster" name="poster" type="file" />
                                      <label htmlFor="poster">
                                        <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span">
                                          <CloudUploadIcon />
                                        </IconButton>
                                     </label>

                                  </Grid>

                                  <Grid item xs={11}>
                                    <TextField 
                                    value={poster.fileName}
                                    id="input-with-icon-grid"
                                    label="Poster for the event"
                                    helperText="Note: .png and .jpg is required"
                                    fullWidth
                                      InputProps={{
                                           readOnly: true,
                                          }}
                                       InputLabelProps={{
                                            shrink: true,
                                       }}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                             <span style={{ color: "red" }}>
                                           {errors.poster}
                                     </span>

                            <br />

                            <Grid container spacing={1} alignItems="flex-end">

                            <Grid item xs={8}>
                                  <TextField 
                                        value={values.description}
                                        onChange={e => setValues({...values, description: e.target.value})}
                                            id="description"
                                            name="description"
                                            label="Description of the Event"
                                            fullWidth
                                            autoComplete
                                            multiline
                                        />
                                </Grid>
                               
                                <br/>
                                  <span style={{ color: "red" }}>
                                           {errors.description}
                                     </span>

                                <Grid item xs={4}>
                                        <TextField 
                                        type="color"
                                        value={values.bgColor}
                                        onChange={e => setValues({...values, bgColor: e.target.value})}
                                            id="color"
                                            name="color"
                                            label="Choose color for the display background of the event"
                                            fullWidth
                                            autoComplete
                                        />
                                    </Grid>

                                </Grid>

                                <Button
                                    type="submit"
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    color="secondary"
                                    className={classes.submit}
                                >
                                    Add Record
                                </Button>

                                    
                                </form>

                            </Container>

                </Paper>
            </DashboardAdmin>
        </div>
    )
}

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  announcement: state.announcement,
  errors: state.errors,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { addAnnouncement }; 

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddEventForm);
```

Then this is my action

```
export const addAnnouncement = data => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/api/announcements/addEvents', data)
    .then(res => dispatch({
        type: ADD_ANNOUNCEMENT_ADMIN,
        payload: res.data,
    }))
    .catch(err => dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
    }));
}
```

Then this is the reducer

```
import {
    ADD_ANNOUNCEMENT_ADMIN,

} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    added: false,
};

const initialState = {
    added: false,
    updated: false,
    deleted: false,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_ANNOUNCEMENT_ADMIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                added:true
            };
        //....

        default: 
            return state;
    }   
};
```

Then this is the route I have for the api endpoint /addEvents

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

//The directory where the files will be stored
const DIR = 'client/public/announcements/';

const Announcements = require('../../models/announcements.model');

const validateAnnouncements = require('../../validation/announcements');

//Diskstorage for sending the files into the assigned Directory
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    // The destination of the file 
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, DIR)
    },
    // what will be the filename of the file uploaded
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {

        // the filename format 
        const filename = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');

        cb(null, `${filename}`);
    }

});


const upload = multer({
     storage: storage,
       fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
            if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {  
                cb(null, true)
            } 
            else {
        
             cb(null, false)
            }
 
       }
});

//@route POST /api/announcements/addEvents
//@desc Add a announcements data
//@access SOA Admin and SOA Head
router.post('/addEvents', upload.single('poster'), (req, res) => {
    const poster = req.file;

    //Url of the app
    const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');

    const today = new Date();

    const { errors, isValid } = validateAnnouncements(req.body);

    if(!isValid) {
        return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }
    else if(poster === undefined) {
        return res.status(400).json({poster: 'Pictures only'})
    }
    else {

    const title = req.body.title;
    
    const date = req.body.date;

    const dateDate = req.body.dateDate;
    const dateTime = req.body.dateTime;
    const venue = req.body.venue;
    const description = req.body.description;
    const backgroundColor = req.body.bgColor;
    const setBy = req.body.setBy;
    const fileName = req.body.fileName;

    const newAnnouncements = new Announcements({
        title,
        date,
        dateDate,
        dateTime,
        backgroundColor,
        venue,
        description,
        poster: url + '/' + poster.path,
        fileName,
        setBy,
        created_at: today
    });

    newAnnouncements.save()
    .then(response => res.json({
        message:'Request submitted',
        datas: {response}
    }))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err));   
    }

    // console.log(newAnnouncements);

});
```

I don't know where's the cause of my app having a proxy error.

This is the message of the error

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/announcements/addEvents from localhost:8000 to http://localhost:6000.
[1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).
```

This is my package.json in react

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.1.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.7.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.48",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@material-ui/system": "^4.9.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "fullcalendar": "^5.1.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=8000 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:6000",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

It cause me a week to debug this and still can't fix why it is having proxy error. It feels like it's having a silent crash in the client side. But still the data is being saved. Then it just refreshes the app on itself.

Giving advice and help on how to fix this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi  What are the things you have tried so far? this way we know what help we can offer.

Comment: So far I just check other problems similar to mine. Like tried to include a header: { 'Content-Type";'multipart/form-data"} in the axios. But still the error appears. it's kinda weird because the data still saves in the database but the app is kinda having a silent crash. It just refresh on itself

Comment: As you can see in the component part. I have a useEffect that when the props.announcement.added is true, it will go to specific page. Which is specified in the props.history.push. But what is happening is that it just refresh the page and not going to page route that i specified in the props.history.push. I can't also check the network because it immediately refreshes the page

Comment: I've fixed my issue now. I just moved the directory of the uploaded files in the root directory. In the backend. Because I've found a issue that the ifle uploaded in the CRA are being hot-reloaded. Check out this link for those who have the same issues as me

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4095
https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/566